# change particular field in output of mysql query

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, rdbms

how to replace all the instances except $FREE$ and ICT16 in the given table fields [image]with an empty field.

please explain with query if possible
In short I want to get the schedule of ICT16 department
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE in your query

```
SELECT ClassID, ClassNo, Type, Days,
  CASE WHEN classAt09 IN ('$FREE$', 'ICT16') THEN classAt09
  ELSE ''
  END as 'classAt09',
  CASE WHEN classAt10...
  -- repeat CASE for all relevant columns
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LfuMvcZwhwaKIMSeosXGUQQV5QO68y00/view?usp=sharing

you can see it here.

Comment: @nish17 Maybe because you did use * first (`SELECT *,`)? Try without the * once to see what you get..

Comment: nope it didn't work as well.. 
 I tried removing the star and placing some coumn name still it didn't work
here's the link ot the screenshot of the image.https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c0vjDBgtykv_vzLZObmsxDrzh76dPPWw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @nish17 Of course it worked, look to the far right in your last screenshot. You can't include any of the `classAtXX` columns as well, only include them as part of the CASE...